# How can I clamp two 325 mm planks while gluing them together?

Tags: wood, woodworking, wooden-furniture, adhesive

I have a base that is 650mm deep.  I'm going to have to glue several planks together to get this depth and, eventually, the last two to make the 650mm base.  The problem is, I don't have (and can't see for sale) 650mm clamps to do this.  As it's 2m long, I'd need quite a few clamps to do it.

Can anyone think of any alternatives?

Comment: I know of one company that makes an extender to connect two clamps to lengths like this: http://www.amazon.com/Bessey-KRX2440-Fixed-Parallel-Includes/dp/B001HSO6W2/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1372714635&sr=8-1&keywords=K+Body%C2%AE+REVO%E2%84%A2+Extender+Kit#productDetails

Comment: Thanks @Steven, the price is a tad out of my budget though.

Comment: I think what you want is a "1000mm F-clamp" (or perhaps 750mm)

Comment: @Craig Would [this ebay item](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/F-Clamp-1000mm-120mm-Wood-Working-Metal-Bar-Quick-Release-Adjustable-Heavy-Duty-/221219759222) do the trick? I can see some on there that go up to over £300!

Comment: If I correctly understand what you want to do, yes.

Answer (score 5):

If Bessey K style are not in the budget, Bessey H pipe end clamps are very economical, with new lengths available for the price of an iron (or steel) pipe.

[image]

Found [these](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Bessey-75in-Series-Clamp-BPC-H34/dp/B0012YNJRO) on Amazon UK

Comment: Chers, what is "Besser style", just triad searching for it and I'm not getting much to do with woodwork back.

Comment: @BanksySan fixed some typos and added a link

Comment: I've got similar ones: [Jorgensen](http://www.amazon.com/Jorgensen-50-4-Inch-Clamp-Fixture/dp/B0000224C9) and [Rockler](http://www.rockler.com/product.cfm?page=17397). Both work well, and you can decide for yourself if it's worth having the "feet" for another $5/each. Don't forget you'll have to go buy the lengths of pipe separately.

Comment: @doresroom I also have the Jorgensen's, but they didn't seem as available in UK as Bessey

Comment: Another advantage to pipe clamps is that you can use couplings to combine several shorter pieces of pipe rather than having to buy the longest possible lengths you need for a given project.  Gives more flexibility with lengths and is easier to store.

Answer (score 1):

What you're wanting are called "Sash clamps".  Some people call them bar clamps.

[image: Sash clamp]

You can join them simply with a good PVA glue. But personally I prefer to dowel them as well for added strength.  With this sort of length you'll want to put at least 3 clamps on the bottom and 2 on top to help keep it flat and wind it up tight to make a nice wide board.

The process looks something like this:

[image: clamping]

[Edge gluing boards together](http://www.familyhandyman.com/woodworking/wood-joints/edge-gluing-boards/view-all)

Make sure you put clamps on top because the pressure can cause the wood to bow out.  Clamping from both sides prevents that bowing and keeps it nice and flat.  Note the edge protector! that's important if you want a nice finish.

They come in different lengths usually around 1+ meters.  They are probably around US$20 each.

Answer (score 0):

I had a bunch of short hand-clamps but needed to clamp something much wider.

So I used pairs of clamps with a length of binding rope to achieve a similar effect.  It wasn't as tight nor straight, but worked well enough.

[image]